# Can you take the withdraw action while prone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, actions, prone

The crawling rules state you can crawl at 5 feet speed, thus a withdraw action should be able to move you 10 feet away.

I feel the answer should be 'no', because it would render without sense the tumbling while crawling option covered within the acrobatics rules, and would render the rogue talent [rogue crawl](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/rogue.html#rogue-talents-rogue-crawl) to move while prone much less advantageous. However, I cannot find anything in neither the crawling or the Withdraw rules to deny this action while prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crawling explicitly provokes an attack of opportunity.

> **Crawling**
>
> You can crawl 5 feet as a move action. Crawling incurs attacks of opportunity from any attackers who threaten you at any point of your crawl. A crawling character is considered prone and must take a move action to stand up, provoking an attack of opportunity.
>   - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Move

As such, I do not believe it would be reasonable to interpret the rules in a way that treats crawling as base speed.

> You may not withdraw using a form of movement for which you don't have a listed speed.
>   - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Withdraw

As normally you so not have a listed crawling speed, I would have to say the rules appear to disallow the action.

Comment: Well, walking or flying also generates an AoO. But the second part of your answer might be the right one. Can the rogue crawl talent be considered as crawl speed? (that might be a new question) http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/rogue.html#rogue-talents-rogue-crawl

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a new question to me.

Comment: Walking or flying only generates an AoO if you leave a threatened square, which is very different from crawling.

Comment: @balacertar No, it provokes *whether or not* you leave the threatened squares.

Comment: As this is no place to discuss how movement AoO works I will just refer to the proper question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75918/moving-within-a-threatened-area-causing-aoo

Comment: So the difference is it theoretically provokes an AoO to crawl INTO a threatened square whereas normal movement would not. Not that you'd likely ever want to crawl into a threatened square.

Comment: @TREB The circumstance I can see for it would be a warrior tripping an enemy in Melee (5') while wielding a reach weapon. The fighter doesn't threaten the enemy right now, but if they crawl 5' away they're going into a threatened square (and not out of one) and provoke according to crawling-specific rules.